Databricks: Using append_flow and apply_changes_into together to ingest data from multiple sources
I have two separate folders in cloud from which I need to ingest and save data in delta tables in SCD2 format. Files from both tables are almost similar, with one folder having an extra column.
I used apply_changes_into to store the data from each folder to a separate table, which worked fine. I created a view using cloud_files, and then created a streaming table (target table) to which I did apply_changes into.
However, after realizing that both tables have a difference of only one column, I wanted to ingest them in same table as SCD Type 2. Using append_flow to add one more source to a streaming table (target) is possible. But when I tried to also apply_changes_into, it started throwing an error and I was not even sure of what is the syntax because the documentation around this is really sparse.
Please propose a solution.
